# Firestore NodeJS throws catch when retrieving document

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to retrieve a firestore document in NodeJS. Any call I make to the database throws a catch error with the results {}. I am able to generate custom tokens to authenticate on my NodeJS server so the setup is correct. Why is my server throwing a catch when attempting to retrieve a document?

```
var firebaseService = require('./service.json');
var admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(firebaseService),
    databaseURL: "https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com"
});
var db = admin.firestore();

exports.test = function(req, callback) {
    // token
    var ref = db.collection('users').doc('72bf07f8-0ae2-474a-b9b3-4386528b17b1');
    ref.get()
    .then(doc => {
        callback(false,doc);
        return
    })
    .catch(err => {
        callback(true,err);
        return ;
    });
}
```

Comment: I discovered by using err.message in the callback I receive the error "@grpc/grpc-js only works on Node ^8.13.0 || >=10.10.0". I have tried installing different versions of Node and still see the same error